# Passing queryset instance django inlineformset factory?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am filtering a queryset and trying to pass the filtered queryset to a Formset instance. However, when I try to render the formset, I get the error Queryset object has no attribute pk.I tried passing queryset instead of instance but when I pass Queryset nothing is being rendered in the template. What could I be doing wrong ?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        data = super(CollectionCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['formset1'] = WorkExperienceFormSet(self.request.POST,instance=WorkExperience.objects.exclude(company_name__isnull=True))
            return data
        else:
        data['formset1'] = WorkExperienceFormSet(instance=WorkExperience.objects.exclude(company_name__isnull=True))

            return data

WorkExperienceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    UserProfile, WorkExperience, form=WorkExperienceForm,
    fields=['company_name', 'start_date','end_date','work_description'], can_delete=True,extra=1,max_num=5
    )

Traceback
<QuerySet [{'id': 20, 'user_id': 6, 'company_name': 'Mumsvillagessss', 'start_date': datetime.date(2013, 5, 21), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 11, 8), 'work_description': 'Test this'}, {'id': 23, 'user_id': 6, 'company_name': 'emmie', 'start_date': datetime.date(2013, 7, 7), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 11, 6), 'work_description': 'jfdjdj'}]>
```

Comment: instance should be an object ... it can be `instance=WorkExperience.objects.exclude(company_name__isnull=True).first()`

Comment: @shourav:- What if I want to pass more than one instance because .first() will only pass the first instance